# Why my text editor is unable to read the built-in functions such as print, in, input etc?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm new to python. For reasons I can't understand, My PyCharm text editor is not reading the built in functions such as print, int, input:

[image]

Can anyone make me understand, why this is happening?

Comment: I don't use PyCharm, but presumably there's a way to get more information about what those red underlines mean. Do you get any more information if you mouse over them? Or right-click? Or move the cursor there? What about the red "!" with a 3 beside it in the top-right corner? Don't be afraid to explore.

Comment: In many other IDEs from JetBrains -- though I can't speak to PyCharm specifically -- this would mean you hadn't configured it to know which compiler/interpreter/runtime to use, and thus which builtins/libraries/etc are available for same.

Comment: As Chris says, if you actually ask PyCharm to show the error messages, they should make the problem obvious. By contrast, without seeing those error messages ourselves, we can't do anything but guess; questions that don't have enough information to be answerable are off-topic here.

Comment: Go into Settings and make sure you have specified an interpreter for the project.

Comment: or just run the code and PyCharm will ask you to set the project interpret (I think it is easier then navigate the settings menu: setting/properties -> Project XXX -> Interpret)